# Sabre getting started V3 AuthToken V3

Tags: sabre

I am trying to access https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v3/auth/token from the postman with valid base64 encoded Authorization header.

What is the valid value for username? Isn't it same which I used for registration. Document showing it as EPR in form 'user-group-domain'. Please help

I am getting an error.

{
"error": "invalid_client",
"error_description": "Credentials are missing or the syntax is not correct"
}

Comment: Did you find the way to use Sabre API with test aplication and client_id/client_secret?

Answer (score 0):

Go to: [https://developer.sabre.com/user/{YOUR_USER}/applications](https://developer.sabre.com/user/%7BYOUR_USER%7D/applications)

There you'll see `YOUR_USER's application`
Your user is what you have below `Client ID` and the password is below `Client Secret`. On that you have: Base64(Base64(Client ID):Base64(Client Secret)) (this is generic, to show how it should be coded.

**This will only work on CERT environment.**

Comment: It is actually base64(client_id:client_secret) for v3 token, but you need other credentials to get the token (username/password) with v3 auth. Although Sabre doc claims that you can use platform for testing without real credentials, you can't find any test credentials which you can use with test applications.

Answer (score 0):

It may be obvious what I am going to talk about, but you must have a SABER GDS authorized user to use this service.
If you do not have an authorized web user you will not be able to make the service work.

Ask Sabre or the agency that you represent this user to access, because without this credential correctly released you will not be able to make any REST / SOAP services work.

You can download the postman functionality package from the link below:

- https://github.com/SabreDevStudio/postman-collections
- https://developer.sabre.com/product-catalog?f%5B0%5D=product_type%3Aapi_reference